# Amazon ElasticMapReduce(EMR) controlling split size / num of mappers

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

How can I change this configuration?
For my application, a split size of 64/128 is too much for me,

and I would like to have a split size of 16 mb for example.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default block size by setting fs.s3n.block.size. Please try like below in your code - jobConf.set("fs.s3n.block.size", *value*);

Please refer the below links as well - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/ElasticMapReduce/latest/emr-dg.pdf

Comment: I'm using hadoop streaming

Comment: Where can i put this setting? fs.s3n.block.size
Im running emr via the aws website, please help me

Comment: I havent tried EMR with streaming, I think you can also change the parameter as given in the below link. But not very sure https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

Comment: Ok i figured it out. Now i have another question: After the Job is done, im having alot of output files. How can i merge them into 1 before sending them to the second task? I have iterative jobs

Comment: I am not getting your question completely. You can give a directory with all the files in it as input to the job. MR job will process all the files in the directory

Comment: Yes, but i want to concatenate them before that.
Also, i can only specify input/output from S3, how can i use HDFS?